# liveBroadcasts->listLiveBroadcasts - even with an ID list - returns no items

Tags: php, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to get attributes of livestreams that are on other channels (not my own) and it seems that everything I try winds up with zero items.  This code compiles a list of (up to) 50 active items, and then calls that endpoint with those ids in hand, and the result is returned: 0 items.  Not an error, just 0 items.

To clarify: SEARCH returns several items.  I collect the VideoID from that collection and request information from list Live Broadcasts.  That returns no items.

If I run this code in debug mode, I can see that 50 items are received from search. Checking each of them, I see that they indeed are active livestreams.  (OK, I didn't check them all.  But I checked many....  https://youtu.be/<VIDEO_ID> revealed active livestreams for each I checked.)

The implication is that only my own livestreams may be retrieved here (youTube documentation doesn't actually say), but that begs the question of the reason for parameters like 'mine' and 'onBehalfOfContentOwner'.

Is there a trick I'm missing here?  Or is this endpoint meant to only return my own channel's livestreams?  Is there an endpoint that will allow retrieval of random livestreams?

```
function getRandomLiveStream() {
    global $service ;

    // We'll search for up to 50 livestreams.. and check each one for a livechat.
    // We'll pass the first match as our desired livestream.

    $queryParms = [ 'maxResults' => 50
                  , 'eventType' => 'live'
                  , 'order' => 'viewCount'
                  , 'q' => 'DRONE|GAME'
                  , 'type' => 'video'
                        ] ;
    $searchResults = $service->search->listSearch('snippet', $queryParms) ;
    if ($searchResults && count($searchResults->items) > 0) {
        $ids = [ ] ;
        foreach ($searchResults->items as $item) { // Compile the list of up to 50 ids
            $ids[] = $item->id->videoId ;
            }
        $queryParms = [ 'maxResults' => count($ids)
                      , 'id' => implode(',', $ids)
                            ] ;
        $liveBroadcastItems = listLiveBroadcasts($queryParms) ;
        if ($liveBroadcastItems) {
            foreach ($liveBroadcastItems as $item) {
                if (($item->statistics->totalChatCount > 0) // Only if there is an active chat
                        && ($item->liveChatId) ) // We need a liveChat ID.  If we have that, return this item.
                    return $item ;
                }
            }
        }
    return false ; // Couldn't find a livestream with chat.
    }



function listLiveBroadcasts($queryParms) {
    global $googleIsHappy ;
    global $service ;
    global $lov ;

    try {
        $queryParms['broadcastType'] = 'all' ;

        $response = $service->liveBroadcasts->listLiveBroadcasts('snippet,contentDetails,status,statistics', $queryParms);
        return $response->items ;
        }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $googleIsHappy = false ;
        $code = $e->getCode() ;
        $message = $e->getMessage() ;
        $json = $message ;
        if ($arr = json_decode($json, true)) {
            $message = $arr['error']['message'] ;
            }
        $string = sprintf("service->%s() failed with code %s, error: %s.\n"
                            , $serviceName, $code, $message) ;
        $lov->writeLogLine($string) ;
        return false ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I can see that 50 items are returned, [...] they indeed are active livestreams", "only my own livestreams may be retrieved". Are you having currently running more than 50 livestreams ? This part is unclear. What do you mean by "I run this code in debug mode" ?

Comment: VSCode interactive development tool allows me to run this code line by line and inspect variables.  That's what I meant about running in debug mode.  I never implied I had a number of concurrently active livestreams.  Not sure where you got that.  I have tried to clarify the issue though.

Comment: I don't use VSCode interactive development tool. Are you able with it to run line by line or just put a lot of `echo` and see where things go wrong ?

Comment: I run step by step, line by line.  It's a visual editor/debugger.  See Xdebug.  Do you have any input about the question?